# Realizando checagem checkbox com jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria se saber como posso complementar o código abaixo para ter como retornar valores em modo de checagem na checkbox o problema e que necessito  que essa checagem seja realizada da seguinte forma mantenha a posição de array criada na hora da marcação dos itens seguindo a ordem dos valores mostrados na mesma posição dentro da textarea bem como o numero que aparece do lado dos itens marcados mostrando as posições em que eles foram selecionados.

O motivo disto e que tenho duas áreas uma que envia os valores da checkbox para o banco de dados e a outra o modo de edição que retorna os valores contidos dentro do banco, o problema e que como esse código gera posição array para os itens marcados ao retornar o valores selecionados contidos dentro do banco de dados esse script não esta retornando as posições da array dos itens no modo de checagem e mesmo colocando valores de checagem nas checkbox não insere esses valores dentro da textarea bem como suas posições de marcação criadas quando tem algum item marcado na checkbox.

```js
var listCheckedOptions = [];
function addToList(checkObj, outputObjID) {
  //Remove do array caso o elemento já esteja inserido
  if (listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj) >= 0) {
    listCheckedOptions.splice(listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj), 1);
  } else {
    if (listCheckedOptions.length >= 2) {
      alert("Máx 2 Elemenos selecionados");
      return checkObj.checked = false;
    }
    listCheckedOptions.push(checkObj);
  }

  document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = ""; //Limpa o textarea
  document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = listCheckedOptions.map(function (o) {
    return o.value;
  }).join('\r\n'); //Adiciona no textarea
  if (!checkObj.checked) checkObj.nextSibling.querySelector('span').innerHTML = '';
  listCheckedOptions.forEach(function (el, i) {
    var span = el.nextSibling.querySelector('span').innerHTML = i + 1;
  });

  return;
}
```

```html
  <form name="myform">
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Oranges" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Oranges <span></span></font>

<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Apples" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Apples <span></span></font>

<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Grapes" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')"><font color="#808080">Grapes <span></span></font>

<br>
<textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="txt1" id="txt1" style="color:#808080" readonly></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Você pode escrever um exemplo do que quer que apareça dentro do textarea?

Comment: Veja só o código atualmente quando você marca um item ele primeiro ao marcar envia o valor na posição em que foi selecionado para a textarea depois coloca um numero indicando a ordem em que ele foi selecionado certo agora se você coloca uma checbox com checked só fica marcado e não emite nem o valor da seleção para textarea nem mesmo a sua posição não mostra o numero do lado do texto mostrando a ordem em que eles foram marcados necessito que em checked ele faça o mesmo.

Comment: Criei um snippet com o seu exemplo, pude ver que a textarea não está na mesma ordem nos checkbox, é este o seu problema?

Comment: Rodrigo, o indice da marcação não está aparecendo apos a checkbox, pois não existe nenhuma tag <span> no html, possivelmente você esqueceu de adiconar eles.

Comment: Quanto ao valor inicial no textarea, acredito que você terá que fazer uma varredura nos checkbox no onload.

Comment: Seria isso Rodrigo: http://jsfiddle.net/dsy0amLf/1/

Comment: O seu jsfiddle apenas não funcionou por um detalhe. todos os seus métodos estavam declarados no onready do jQuery, por tanto não estavam visíveis para o DOM, apenas precisei fazer uma pequena alteração para corrigir:
http://jsfiddle.net/dsy0amLf/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ver se o código abaixo é o que deseja.

```js
var frutas = document.getElementsByName("fruit[]");
var txt1 = document.getElementById("txt1");

frutas = [].slice.apply(frutas);
var listCheckedOptions = frutas.filter(function (fruta, indice) {
    return fruta.checked;
}).sort(function (fruta, indice) {
    return fruta.dataset.order;
});


function addToList(checkObj, outputObj) {
  //Remove do array caso o elemento já esteja inserido
  if (listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj) >= 0) {
    listCheckedOptions.splice(listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj), 1);
  } else {
    if (listCheckedOptions.length >= 2) {
      alert("Máx 2 Elemenos selecionados");
      return checkObj.checked = false;
    }
    listCheckedOptions.push(checkObj);
  }
  
  if (!checkObj.checked) {
    checkObj.parentNode.querySelector('span').innerHTML = '';  
    delete checkObj.dataset.order;
  }
  return updateValores(outputObj);
}

var updateValores = function (outputObj) {
  outputObj.value = ""; //Limpa o textarea
  outputObj.value = listCheckedOptions.map(function (o) {
    return o.value;
  }).join('\r\n'); //Adiciona no textarea  
  
  listCheckedOptions.forEach(function (fruta, indice) {
    var span = fruta.parentNode.querySelector('span');
    fruta.dataset.order = indice + 1;
    span.innerHTML = indice + 1;
  });

  return;
}

frutas.forEach(function (fruta, indice) {
  fruta.onclick = function () {
    addToList(this, txt1);
  };
});
updateValores(txt1);
```

```html
<form name="myform">  
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Oranges" data-order="2" checked />  
    <font color="#808080">Oranges</font>
    <span></span>
  </label><br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Apples" />
    <font color="#808080">Apples</font>
    <span></span>
  </label><br>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Grapes" data-order="1" checked />
    <font color="#808080">Grapes</font>
    <span></span>
  </label><br>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="10" name="txt1" id="txt1" style="color:#808080"  readonly></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Só uma coisa que necessito alem do que você já fez e que no caso a array esta retornando os valores de checagem na ordem da listagem certo só que tipo se eu tiver nessa ordem no se eu tiver os itens marcados no banco de dados nesta ordem os valores primeiro Grapes depois Oranges como posso fazer ficar o Grapes 1 e Oranges 2, no complemento que você fez.

Comment: atualizei o exemplo, neste caso aconselho usar uma propriedade data-custom para guardar a ordem que vem do banco.
você pode até atualizar o valor desta propriedade, a exemplo do código acima, mas isto não vai afetar o resultado, portanto sendo opcional.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda agora sim ficou tudo do geito que eu preciso.